# How to create a default image per taxonomy term?

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I want to associate a different default image with each taxonomy term.

I saw this module - https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_image - but it's in alpha.

Anyone got any recommendations how to do this?

Many thanks!

Comment: Taxonomy Terms are content entities (like nodes and media) and can be fielded. You can add an image field to them and then configure a view mode to display the image.

Answer (score 0):

When creating a vocabulary you can add a image field this is the only way to add a default image for all future taxonomy terms (in that vocab) 
so then when you create the term you would simply add your image to that term be it "default" or other.